# fork() and execvp() unexpected outcome when used with sudo

Tags: c, terminal, fork, sudo, execvp

So when i invoke this program without sudo. It works fine.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(fork() == 0) execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    // else wait(NULL);
}
```

But with sudo (when i need to input my password) it gives an odd output:

```
pasha@skynet:~$ sudo ./a.out bash
[sudo] password for pasha:         
pasha@skynet:~$ root@skynet:~#
```

Then on any input the terminal terminates. Further it only happens on a newly spawned terminal. And when the parent waits for the child the problem with sudo disappears.

Can someone explain why ?

Comment: You have the line that fixes the problem, but you commented it out.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I was trying to know why this happens. I have mentioned that it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> why this happens

You are `fork`ing your process, so there are two processes now.

One process is the parent, the process run by your shell, like `shell -> fork() -> exec(sudo) -> exec(./a.out)`. The parent terminates, because `fork` returns with nonzero and then `main()` reaches closing `}`. `main` by default returns `0`. So shell sees that your program terminated with exit status 0. And your shell greets you with a new `pasha@skynet:~$` prompt line after your program is done.

The other process is the child, run from your program where `fork` returned zero, like `shell -> fork() -> exec(sudo) -> exec(./a.out) -> fork() -> exec(bash)`. The child process is `bash`, it prints `root@skynet:~#` (it was run after `sudo`) and waits for input.

Those two processes are running at the same time - ie. your shell (from which you executed `sudo ./a.out`) and the newly `bash` run from your program. Both those programs try to read and write to the same input and output at the same time.

The child process, ie. `bash`, needs to have exclusive control over the input in the terminal. So the child process `bash` executes [tcsetpgrp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetpgrp). But your shell is that one that is controlling your terminal, not the child process. So the child process either receives [signal SIGTTOU](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html) or maybe SIGTTIN upon trying to read from the input. Then the child bash executed the default handler for the signals - it terminates.

Running `sudo bash &` from your shell would cause a similar problem to the one that your program causes.

Comment: Using the same logic we should expect exactly same behavior with `./a.out bash`, but when i run and check `ps` i get an additional running bash processes.

Comment: I get the same behavior. The child bash prints the prompt and reads init scripts and prints `bash: initialize_job_control: no job control in background: Bad file descriptor` and exits

Comment: So maybe this behavior is version specific. I have `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`  btw.

Comment: I couldn't understand how the child process getting terminated will cause the terminal to close. The session leader is still alive. Besides the child bash is in the foreground process group (i have checked `ps`) just before i type any input. Also `SIGTTOU` and `SIGTTIN` does not cause a bash process to end.

Answer (score -1):

Your program is correct; try it out with "ls" instead of "bash",

```
$ ./a.out ls -al /tmp
```

The reason why it does not seem to work with `bash` is that bash
expect the process to be the group leader of the [*terminal foreground
process
group*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tcsetpgrp.3p.html), which
it isn't.

That said, while the program is correct, it's severe lack of error
handling is offending :-). For example, when calling a program that
does not exist, `execvp()` returns with an error (as opposed to not
returning at all) which is ignored. With the effect that ... well
... you can only guess if it worked.

```
$ ./a.out frobozzzzz
$ # (hm)
```

Here's my incarnation of it. Longer. Handling errors. Seeing how it
went after child terminated.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid, terminated;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1 /*unlikely*/) {
        perror("fork()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (pid == 0 /*child*/) {
        if (execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]) != 0) { // when argv[1] is no
                                              // progrm in path
            perror("execvp()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else
            assert(!"not getting here because successful exec() never returns");
    }

    // optional: wait for child to terminate, and print diagnostics
    terminated = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    if (terminated == -1) {
        perror("waitpid()");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (terminated == pid) { // how come those not be equal?
        if (WIFEXITED(status))
            fprintf(stderr, "child terminated with exit status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
            fprintf(stderr, "child terminated by %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "see \"man waidpid\" for what that could be\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The program is not correct. You're not supposed to exit while you still have child processes that are using the terminal.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: please be more precise as to how the program would exit before the child. Apart from that, why would a program be incorrect because of this?

Comment: Because now there are two processes running, both of which think the terminal belongs to them, and it's generally unpredictable which process will get the text that you type from then on.

Comment: Given that on my system bash initially complains, without sudo, that job control is not available, I wanted to point out that bash seems like the wrong test program. The definition of correctness is a different thing because the original question does not say anything about intention. Dogmatically stating "exit before wait is incorrect" is not something that leads to understanding, IMHO. Such dogmata would suddenly render daemon programs incorrect, for example.

Comment: I'm not saying that exit before wait is always incorrect. I'm saying it's incorrect when the child process is one that needs the user's terminal.

Comment: Yes, this is why I say that bash seems like the wrong test program. The user sure does not want to know how to care about terminal ownership. Dogmatically saying that "any program that does not handle errors is incorrect", I wrote a "fixed" version of it in my answer, with the added benefit that it also waits.

Comment: @JörgFaschingbauer when i type ^C in the mangled terminal. The input is received by the child `bash` process. This means that the child `bash` process is actually in foreground process group.